# About ncurses header file

Tags: fedora, compiling, libraries, ncurses

I' running Fedora 15 (32-bit). But I can`t compile and run an ncurses program. Also, colours are not working in the terminal. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You need to give more information to explain your question.  What ncurses program are you trying to build?  How do you know you can't compile the program (Are you getting a specific error message?)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have curses-devel packages installed?

```
sudo yum search curses

ncurses.x86_64 : Ncurses support utilities
ncurses-devel.i686 : Development files for the ncurses library
ncurses-devel.x86_64 : Development files for the ncurses library
ncurses-libs.i686 : Ncurses libraries
ncurses-libs.x86_64 : Ncurses libraries
```

If not install them :

```
sudo yum install -y ncurses ncurses-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the ncurses-devel package to be able to build programs using it.

Besides, Fedora 15 has discontinued support a year or so back, update.